# HowTo implement "update" in Hibernate JPA2

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

Could someone provide a simple example that demonstrates how to implement a simple "update" method? This one does not update

```
@Override
public void update(final BS bs) {
    BS fullBs = em.find(BS.class, bs.getId());
    BS merged = this.em.merge(fullBs);
    this.em.flush();
}
```

Thanks

ER

Comment: why you think its should work? you just finding an entity and then saving(merging) it back. without any changes.

Comment: I am not aware of what merge actually does. However, re-reading my lines with your comment I realise my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates in hibernate are implemented using dirty checking rather than explicit update calls.  For example in the method above if you `find()` your BS entity and then modify a property and then call `flush()` you will see an SQL update being generated.  Without the modification `flush()` will decide there is nothing to do.

Example

```
@Override
public void update(final BS bs) {
    BS fullBs = em.find(BS.class, bs.getId());
    fullBs.setMyProperty("hello");
    this.em.flush();
}
```

When you do the `find()` the entity is loaded by the JPA provider (hibernate in this case) and hibernate will give you the entity AND it keeps an internal record of the entity state at the point it was loaded PLUS it hold a reference to the entity it returned.

Then when `flush()` is called hibernate dirty checks every entity in its cache (called the first-level cache or session cache).  The dirty checks consists of checking every property of the entity you got with the internal state record.  If there are any differences the entity is "dirty" and an SQL update will be generated.

Note that `flush()` is not a transactional commit.  It simply says, "please persist any changes made in the session to the database now" which will involve insert/update/delete statements.

The `merge()` is not required for a simple update.

Also you don't generally call `flush()` explicitly.  It's normally better to let hibernate do that.  Hibernate will flush the session when it needs to, which will usually be on a transaction commit, so the commit will do the flush for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone provide a simple example that demonstrates how to implement a simple "update" method? This one does not update (...)

Well, it really depends on the state of the entity you want to udpate (managed vs detached) but your code is definitely useless. Le'ts analyze it:

```
1. public void update(final BS bs) {
2.     BS fullBs = em.find(BS.class, bs.getId());
3.     BS merged = this.em.merge(fullBs);
4.     this.em.flush();
5. }
```

1. As I said, the state of the `bs` entity passed as parameter is unclear. Anyway...
2. You then use its `Id` to load a managed entity into `fullBs` and... you **don't change anything**.
3. Then you try to `merge` an already managed entity which is totally unnecessary (JPA provides [automatic state detection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1340) for managed entities).
4. And you `flush` the changes... that don't exist :)

So your method isn't currently doing anything, as you experimented.

Back to the question now:

- if you want to update a *managed* entity, you should not invoke any method, JPA will detect any state changes automatically and persist the changes at `flush` time
- if you want to update a *detached* entity, you should use `merge` (and return the merged instance).

#### See also

- [JPA implementation patterns: Saving (detached) entities](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/23/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/)

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 3.1.1 "EntityManager Interface"
  - Section 3.2 "Entity Instance’s Life Cycle"
  - Section 3.2.7 "Detached Entities"
  - Section 3.2.8 "Managed Instances"

Comment: Thank you very much for the accurate explanation and the reference list which is extraordinarily useful for a JPA beginner like me.